# How to write PHP code inside MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am confused how to create loop inside MySQL query.

I have this query:

```
<?php
    $arr = explode(',', $features);
    $query_spicy = "
    SELECT wposts.*             
        FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
    INNER
        JOIN ( SELECT post_id
               FROM $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
                    WHERE ('; 
                                ( wpostmeta.meta_key = 'features' AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '%test1%' )
                            OR 
                                ( wpostmeta.meta_key = 'features'AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '%test2%' )
                            OR 
                                ( wpostmeta.meta_key = 'features'AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '%test3%' )
                            OR
                                ( wpostmeta.meta_key = 'features'AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '%test4%' )
                            OR
                                ( wpostmeta.meta_key = 'features'AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '%test5%' )
                    ')
                    GROUP BY post_id
            ) AS t ON t.post_id = wposts.ID WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish' AND wposts.post_type = 'book' ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC";
?>
```

And I want generate bellow part dynamic with for loop:

```
( wpostmeta.meta_key = 'features' AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '%test1%' ) OR 
( wpostmeta.meta_key = 'features' AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '%test2%' ) OR 
( wpostmeta.meta_key = 'features' AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '%test3%' ) OR
( wpostmeta.meta_key = 'features' AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '%test4%' ) OR
( wpostmeta.meta_key = 'features' AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '%test5%' )
```

Note: test1, test2, test3, test4 and test5, I am getting from this `$arr`.

I hope you understand my question and I will thankful if you help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's certainly possible to achieve exactly what you're asking for, but I feel like there's probably a better way to do what you want than this.

Answer (score 2):

try something like

```
$arr = explode(',', $features);
$conditions = array();

foreach($arr as $feature){
    $condition[] = "( wpostmeta.meta_key = 'features' AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '{$feature}' )";
}
$query = "SELECT ...". join("OR",$conditions);
```

But you can simply do something like wpostmeta.meta_key = 'feature' and wpostmet IN($features)

I think second solution is better and faster.

Comment: Hi thanks you your answer but can you guide me with full explanation. Thanks.

Comment: First here is more info for mysql in statements: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp 

Ok I assume you already have a list of features, concatenated with a comma (dont forget to add ' to them).

So you will need to create a query that looks like this: 
...continue after while

Comment: SELECT post_id
FROM $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wpostmeta.meta_key = 'features' AND meta_value IN ($feature)

You can also see INSTR function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr

Answer (score 0):

Try this

wpostmeta.meta_key = ".$features." AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '%test1%'

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $arr = explode( ',', $features );

    $query_spicy = "
    SELECT wposts.*             
        FROM {$wpdb->posts wposts}
    INNER
        JOIN ( SELECT post_id
               FROM {$wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta}
                    WHERE (";

    $tmp = array();
    foreach( $arr as $value )
    {
        $tmp[] = "( wpostmeta.meta_key = 'features' AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '%{$value}%' )";
    }

    $query_spicy .= implode( ' OR ', $tmp );
    $query_spicy .= ")
                    GROUP BY post_id
            ) AS t ON t.post_id = wposts.ID WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish' AND wposts.post_type = 'book' ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

FWIIW:

Just set an array to contain the data you need to insert then use foreach to loop through it.

```
$sql="SELECT wposts.*             
        FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
    INNER
        JOIN ( SELECT post_id
               FROM $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
                    WHERE ('; ";
foreach($arrayoftestdata as $test)
    {
    $sql.="( wpostmeta.meta_key = 'features' AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '%$test%' ) OR ";
    }

$sql.="')
                    GROUP BY post_id
            ) AS t ON t.post_id = wposts.ID WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish' AND wposts.post_type = 'book' ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC";
```